# Luxon DateTime fromISO wrong offset when zone is specified

Tags: javascript, datetime, luxon

When I'm trying to create a DateTime from an input datetime whose value is "2020-03-23T00:00:00" and if I use a zone 'Europe/Berlin', the DateTime gives a +25 offset instead +1:

```
const isoDate = "2020-03-23T00:00:00";
const newDate = DateTime.fromISO(isoDate, {zone : 'Europe/Berlin'})

const dateToString = newDate.toString(); // logs 2020-03-23T00:00:00.000+25:00
```

this code gives a timestamp of 1584831600000, that is Saturday, 21 March 2020 23:00:00 UTC and should be 1584918000000  Sunday, 22 March 2020 23:00:00 UTC

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/8uhap6cb/)

What I'm doing wrong??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using an old version of Luxon (`1.3.2` in the jsfiddle), your issue will be solved if you upgrade Luxon version.

Working snippet using version `1.22.0`:

```js
const DateTime = luxon.DateTime;
const isoDate = "2020-03-23T00:00:00";
const newDate = DateTime.fromISO(isoDate, {zone : 'Europe/Berlin'})
    
const dateToString = newDate.toString();

console.log(newDate)
console.log(dateToString)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@1.22.0/build/global/luxon.js"></script>
```

More info on closed GitHub issues:

- [Wrong date calculation in certain chrome version after using setZone()](https://github.com/moment/luxon/issues/619)
- [Timezone +26:00 bug in Chrome 80+](https://github.com/moment/luxon/issues/657)